# Converting Unix Timestamp to standard time in Ruby but getting strange error in console

Tags: ruby

Basically I'm just trying to sift through a csv with unix timestamps, and not sure what is going wrong as I looked at other solutions on this site.

Error

> `csv_parsing.rb:13`:in `at': can't convert String into an exact number (TypeError)

My unix_timestamps_array variable is an array of strings composed of unix timestamps for example "1237178109" but dont feel like attaching the csv. I can confirm that before ln 7 I am getting the array of unix timestamps in the terminal.

```
require 'csv'
require 'date'

csv = CSV.read('sample_data.csv', headers: true)

unix_time_str_array = csv['created_at']

unix_time_int_array = unix_time_str_array.map {|e| e.to_i }

converted_time = unix_time_int_array.each {|timestamp| Time.at(timestamp)}

p converted_time
```

Comment: note I am aware of Time.now but this is a bit different since I am reading from a file etc.

Comment: nvm case closed. #each needs to be #map to get utc time. Maybe someone can explain subtle difference? I know each iterates over each element in an array and is the ruby way of looping and map applies the logic of the block to each element of the array and outputs a new array. Why didnt the first case work???

Comment: each does returns the initial collection despite of what happens in the block, whereas `map` returns modified collectio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a [Numeric](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Numeric.html) instance, not string:

```
Time.at("1237178109")
#=> TypeError: can't convert String into an exact number
```

But

```
Time.at(1237178109)
#=> 2009-03-16 06:35:09 +0200
```

Comment: I had a feeling that may be the case... Thanks!

Comment: my output still seems to be not converting the 10 digit unix timestamp to utc standards. Ill edit post above for what I currently have....

Comment: @cristodagama show what you get and the desired output

Comment: The first unix ts in array is 1309380645, which should read 2011-06-29 21:50:45 according to calculators online

However the first element in my array is this 1309380645 aka it never converted